# Custom message at passwords miss matched in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

How to get a custom error message at passwords (password and confirm_password) miss matched failure in Zend framwork 2 (ZF2)?

I am using following code:

```
    $this->add(array(            
        'name'       => 'password',            
        'required'   => true, 
        'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'      => 8,
                        'max'      => 15,
                        'messages' => array(

                            'stringLengthTooShort' => 'Please enter password minimum 8 character!',
                            'stringLengthTooLong' => 'Please enter password maximum 15 character!',
                        )
                    ),
                ),
        ),
    ));


    //Confirm Password validation 
     $this->add(array(            
        'name'       => 'confirm_password',            
        'required'   => true, 
        'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        ),

        'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'      => 8,
                        'max'      => 15,
                        'messages' => array(

                            'stringLengthTooShort' => 'Please enter password minimum 8 character!',
                            'stringLengthTooLong' => 'Please enter password maximum 15 character!',
                        )
                    ),
                ),

                array( 
                    'name' => 'identical', 
                    'options' => array(
                        'token' => 'password',
                        'messages' => array(
                            \Zend\Validator\identical::NOT_EQUAL => 'The password is mis matched'
                        )
                    ) 
                ), 
        ),
    ));
```

I am using a token for confirm passwords and want to show custom message if token fail.
so i use following code to show custom message:

```
\Zend\Validator\identical::NOT_EQUAL => 'The password is mis matched'
```

But i am getting following error:

```
 Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'NOT_EQUAL' in C:\wamp\www\zend\module\*******
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct class constant is `NOT_SAME`, try using that instead

```
\Zend\Validator\Identical::NOT_SAME => 'The password is mis matched'
```

https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/Identical.php#L21